# C++: Linker issue using template and boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I am trying to write a class called "Timer" that wraps around boost::asio::deadline_timer, with the added functionality of making each deadline_timer run in its own thread (independent from each other).

Unfortunately, I am not able to call the typedef I have defined in my own class with boost::bind (the following will make my question more clear).

In my "Timer" class, the signature for my asyncWait() is as follows (and calls deadline_timer.async_wait()):

```
template <typename WaitHandler>
void Timer::asyncWait(WaitHandler handler) { ... }
```

And I am trying to call this method from within a method of the class "Server", as such:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<Timer> mButton;
// some code
mButton->asyncWait(boost::bind(&Server::foo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

With method:

```
void Server::foo(const boost::system::error_code& error) { ... }
```

But the following error now shows up during the linker, which I do not understand:

```
error: undefined reference to 'void Timer::asyncWait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Server, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Server*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > >(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Server, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Server*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This gets printed for calling mButton->asyncWait() in the Server method. I am not getting why it is compiling but it is not able to link. The class "Timer" gets added as a shared library to the compilation so it doesn't seem to be the actual issue here. What could be wrong please, and how can I please fix it?

Comment: Why does the title talk about `std::bind` when the code uses `boost::bind`? Is there something missing from the question? Is that a mistake?

Comment: Create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Be sure to include the compilation/linking steps you're using.

Comment: Sorry that should have been boost::bind David, I will edit and fix this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the implementation of asynchWait() is not visible at the point, where you instantiate the function template. Make sure, that the implementation is visible to the compiler when you use the function, for example by implementing the function in the same header, where you declared the function.

Explanation: Usually, the compiler generates only machine code for not template functions. For template functions the compiler defers the generation of machine code to the point, where the actual types for the template instantiation are known. This is, because it can make a huge different from type to type. The code to take the sum of two integers is most likely very different from the code to sum two containers or vectors.

Comment: I did think that was the case, but I have other public member functions of Timer which are called before calling asyncWait() and they compile and link without any issue. Those functions are defined in the same file as asyncWait(), so I am not sure why only asyncWait() fails to be linked.

Comment: Are those functions templates too? It should be quit easy to see if my suggestion fixes your problem, so please give it a try. :-)

Comment: Those functions are not template. Just tried putting the implementation inside the header where the function signature was and it worked! Thanks a lot! I am extremely confused why my header / source file combo is not working for the template function (but is working for all other functions). I thought my template function signature was wrong to use with boost::bind in the first place.

Comment: I've added some more explanation, I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, but I am not understanding how putting the implementation of the function in the header file (rather than the source file) changes the problem. It still has to generate machine code for each type that is used (for the template), wether the code is in the header or source file. Does my question makes sense please?

Comment: Yes, your question makes sense. It's simply, because the compiler has to see the implementation (the code) of the template function, when it comes to generating the machine code. When the compiler can not see the implementation, it will not generate machine code. No error will be generated during compiletime, because there could be an other compilation unit that might generate the required template instantiation.

Comment: Ah ok that completely makes sense now! Thanks a lot, this was a stupid mistake of mine :) Thank you!